# Raising Battle Points with Bot Matches

Tags: dota-2

I've read it somewhere that bot matches allegedly boosts battle points? Can anyone help me in confirming this with verifiable source(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think where you read it, they're not talking about the actual **Bot match** but the **Co-op match**.

A Bot match is:

On your own playing with bots

A Co-op match is:

With other players and bots.

The [wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Battle_Points) says this:

> **In Co-op matches you only earn Battle Points for won matches and only if the difficulty was at least 'easy'.**

**Off topic:**

Co-op bot matches can also be used to get out of low priority

Comment: Big thanks man! P.S. that low-prio tip is very informative

Comment: @whitehatwannabe No problem man.